# LaCie 5big Network 2 drive no longer shows up on the network

Tags: networking, nas, lacie

I'm trying to see if I can fix my friend's NAS which apparently has some pretty important data on it that wasn't saved anywhere else.  They actually had the Geeksquad look at it and they've come to the same conclusion I have so far, but I figured I would ask the internet before I gave the thing back to them and said Geeksquad was right.

Anyways, they have this [5 drive RAIDed NAS](http://www.lacie.com/products/product.htm?id=10485) which apparently just stopped showing up on their network.  I borrowed it from them to see if I could figure it out.  It turns on just fine and my router assigns it an IP address, but the IP address just takes me to a blank LaCie dashboard screen.  It's weird because it's clearly running it's web server because it's just a gray background with an empty white box and "(c) LaCie 2010" at the bottom.  No content at all.

Additionally, I tried installing the LaCie Network Assistant on my home computer and it says it cannot find any network disks.  I've tried the "wake up a device" where I enter the mac address, but that doesn't do anything.

All the lights are solid blue on the front and over all the drives so it doesn't appear a drive has failed or something.  Even so, that wouldn't really explain the blank dashboard right?

Does anyone have any ideas at this point?

Comment: I highly recommend accessing the drive from something other than its network interface. It looks like the drive has 2 eSATA and 2 USB - use them so you can circumvent all the web server B.S. You can actually use some real tools against the drive to recover data if you can get to it through USB/eSATA - not so on the network interface. If the data is that important I would start using dd to image the drives for recovery - a little tricker on RAID.

Answer (score 1):

Find another Lacie 5big Network 2 unit and swap the HDD's. If the new unit is good, the drives will be detected and you can access the data on them. You might need the Laice Network Assist tool to connect and ... Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Probably a Cap problem on the board... they need to replaced, if it is still under warranty contact lacie for a replacement. if not pull the board and look for bulging or burnt capacitors. find a good TV repair shop and you'll be backup. I learned the hard way, always keep a cloned boot drive in your file cabinet as a backup.. boot drive seem to corrupt easily

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you offer any explanation on why you believe this is caused by a bad capacitor?